# How to operate on alternate lines in a file

Tags: python, file, line

I wanted to know how to operate on alternate lines in a file (in particular I have a text consisting of a regular line and a line written backwards which I would reverse with [::-1]). I'll start with an example:

```
Easter eggs,
,eulb dna wolleY
Easter eggs,
.uoy dna em roF


Easter eggs,
,teews ydnaC
Easter eggs,
.tae ot doog erA
```

And I want to have:

```
Easter eggs,
Yellow and blue,
Easter eggs,
For me and you.


Easter eggs,
Candy sweet,
Easter eggs,
Are good to eat.
```

How can I do this? Because I would like to be able to do it also with empty lines (one or more of a new line, that is '\t') as in the example. All this by scrolling through a file.
Thanks

**EDIT:**
**For @Mr. Hobo**
The error is in the last paragraph

```
ἄνδρα μοι ἔννεπε, μοῦσα, πολύτροπον, ὃς μάλα πολλὰ
πλάγχθη, ἐπεὶ τροίης ἱερὸν πτολίεθρον ἔπερσεν:
πολλῶν δ' ἀνθρώπων ἴδεν ἄστεα καὶ νόον ἔγνω,
πολλὰ δ' ὅ γ' ἐν πόντῳ πάθεν ἄλγεα ὃν κατὰ θυμόν,
ἀρνύμενος ἥν τε ψυχὴν καὶ νόστον ἑταίρων.


ἀλλ' οὐδ' ὣς ἑτάρους ἐρρύσατο, ἱέμενός περ:
αὐτῶν γὰρ σφετέρῃσιν ἀτασθαλίῃσιν ὄλοντο,
νήπιοι, οἳ κατὰ βοῦς ὑπερίονος ἠελίοιο
ἤσθιον: αὐτὰρ ὁ τοῖσιν ἀφείλετο νόστιμον ἦμαρ.
τῶν ἁμόθεν γε,
θεά θύγατερ,
διός, εἰπὲ καὶ ἡμῖν.

,νορθελὄ νὺπἰα νογύφ ιοσὅ ,ςετνάπ νὲμ ιολλἄ 'θνἔ
νασσαλάθ ὲδἠ ςετόγυεφεπ ετ νόμελόπ ,νασἔ ιοκἴο
,ςὸκιανυγ ὲδἠ νονέμηρχεκ υοτσόν νοἶο 'δ νὸτ
νωάεθ αῖδ ὼψυλακ εκυρἔ 'ιντόπ ηφμύν
.ιανἶε νισόπ ηνέμοιαλιλ ,ισῖορυφαλγ ισσέπσ νἐ
```

Comment: what is the problem you are facing? can you post the code you have tried

Comment: actually at the moment I was just forming the idea but, not being very experienced, I wanted to know if there was an "easy" way to do it. I had thought of putting a counter for the lines (obviously using an "if" first to see if the line starts with a character or is empty): this count was based on working on even lines

Comment: does the empty lines in output matters?

Comment: The easy way: `for is_reversed, line in zip(itertools.cycle((False, True)), fileobj): if is_reversed: line = line.rstrip('\n')[::-1] + '\n'`

Comment: @deadshot I guess OP wants the blank line separately as he mentioned!

Comment: yes, the empty lines matters

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have the text in `file.txt` then you can do:

```py
with open("file.txt") as f:
    content = f.readlines()
    
content = [value.strip()[::-1] if idx % 2 != 0 else value.strip() for idx, value in enumerate(content)]
print(content)

>> ['Easter eggs,', 'Yellow and blue,', 'Easter eggs,', 'For me and you.', '', '', 'Easter eggs,', 'Candy sweet,', 'Easter eggs,', 'Are good to eat.']
```

**Explanation:** I'm reading the file, [as suggested in this community question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3277503/how-to-read-a-file-line-by-line-into-a-list) and then, enumerating the contents to check if the file index is divisible by 2 (`idx % 2 != 0`).

**EDIT:** If you want the newline characters and want to paste the message in a single string, you can do this:

```py
print('\n'.join(content))
```

Output:

```
Easter eggs,
Yellow and blue,
Easter eggs,
For me and you.


Easter eggs,
Candy sweet,
Easter eggs,
Are good to eat.
```

Comment: @deadshot Yes, it does remove newline characters, keeps the blank lines as the OP has requested?

Comment: Thanks, that worked for this text, but when I only have one blank line (instead of two as in the example), it no longer works. How can I do?

Comment: @orsettomorbido can you please share the error/output you are getting. I was able to get two blank lines as in the `output` I have shared.

Comment: I edited the question so you can see what a problem it gives me

Comment: i think it gives error because odd and even lines swap if there is only a blank space. in fact I should only turn the even lines (but without counting the spaces because those swap even and odd lines every now and then)

Comment: I can't understand greek, but I think what you have pointed out is correct. It is not a question of doing operations on alternate lines. The last paragraph is giving a result opposite of what is required because it is working on alternate lines.

Comment: in the last paragraph the program inverts the correct lines for me (and those already inverted remain like this). how can i fix?

Answer (score 0):

Using readlines and while loop

```py
f = open("demofile.txt", "r")
lines = f.readlines();
I = 0 # start lines index
Result = ""
while I < len(lines):
    line = lines[I]
    # start index if 0 so every reverse line will have odd index (1, 3, 5 etc).
    if not I % 2 == 0:
        Result += line.strip()[::-1] + '\n'
        I += 1
        continue
    Result += line
    I += 1

print(Result)
```

Comment: i dont know why but i tried to run it and it gets stuck in a loop. in particular it crashes me on "continue"

Comment: It should work now. I accidentally forgot to increment I

Comment: new edit: this will work now, earlier i had used my mobile phone for answering thats why i accidentally used readline() instead of readlines()

Comment: thanks, now it works, but it gives me a problem if after several paragraphs there is only one blank line (instead of two as in the example). That is, it reverses the even lines and leaves the odd ones turned

Comment: i think it gives error because odd and even lines swap if there is only a blank space. in fact I should only turn the even lines (but without counting the spaces because those swap even and odd lines every now and then)